# Extract audio frames from live stream with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, live-streaming

I would like to perform live voice activity detection and audio analysis on a live video stream.

I currently use FFMPEG to extract the audio:

```
ffmpeg -i https://example.com/live/stream.m3u8 -vn -c:a copy audio.aac
```

The issue is that the aac file will only be valid once the stream has finished.

How can I output an audio stream or audio chunks/frames (just like image frames) so that I can analyze them without waiting for the end of the video stream?

Comment: Output to a different format, such as wav.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1) Single File

If you need a single file that contains all of the audio stream you can choose a container like mp4 with fragmentation.

```
ffmpeg -i https://example.com/live/stream.m3u8 -vn -c:a aac -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov audio.mp4
```

`frag_keyframe` = fragmented output
`empty_moov` = output will be 100% fragmented

## Option 2) Multiple files

If you prefer small files that you can process one by one use the segmented output.

```
ffmpeg -i https://example.com/live/stream.m3u8 -vn -c:a aac -f segment -segment_time 5 audio%03d.aac
```

`segment_time` = create every 5 seconds a new file